# multiple windows for a windows/mac/linux desktop flutter app

Tags: linux, flutter, windows, macos, desktop

I need to implement multiple windows in a flutter desktop app.
Im astonished that this is not possible out of the box.

For example I have a tray app, with a settings window im require to have.
then i want an additional welcome window when the app starts.

I need 3 windows:

- tray window to display some contents
- welcome window on start
- settings window to make some application settings.

Very common basale rquirements for a desktop app.

I would like to know an example of how to implement my usecase in flutter in a clean way if its not officially supported i look for a package or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet available on the Flutter SDK, but the multi-window project is in active development as of the moment. I don't think this will be available anytime soon since there have been no official announcements yet.

You can track the status of development here: https://github.com/orgs/flutter/projects/39/views/1.

There is also an open ticket in which this feature is being discussed (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701).

But for as of now you can use the package https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_multi_window as it does something similar, you can spawn multiple app and each will be treated as a individual window.

I have used the same in one of my plugin, you can get some ideas from there as well: https://pub.dev/packages/infospect.